# Change voice in android

Tags: android, audio, playback

I am using media recorder to record the voice but I want to play the voice in female tone or vice versa.
Basically i have a media player sound and when I play it, it runs fine but now I have recorded my voice using media recorder and I want to play it female tone?
How can I change the male voice to female voice or female voice to male voice?
I have also tried to use soundpool class but it increases or decreases the frequency. It does not change the tone or pitch of voice.

Answer (score 0):

You *are* changing the pitch when you change the frequency. However, just increasing or decreasing the playback frequency is unlikely to make a male voice sound female or vice versa. It'll just sound like a distorted version of the original voice.

A female voice is likely to contain more energy in the higher end of the speech frequency spectrum, and less in the lower end. The opposite would be the case for a male voice.
What *you're* doing in effect is move *all* energy upwards or downwards in the spectrum, which will not sound natural.

The theory of human speech is much too broad a subject to cover at a Q&A site like StackOverflow. So my recommendation would be for you to get a book on the subject, or use a search engine to find some research papers or scientific articles.